# Cannot delete svn changelist

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, changelist

I recently created a changelist "test" in tortoise svn. I added various pending files with changes to this changelist. I then checked in those files and the changelist disappeared (as expected as there were no more associated files).

The problem started to arise whereby the changelist keeps reappearing randomly when file (that were not ever associated with the changelist) have pending changes.

I have tried everything as listed in the documentation to remove all files from the changelist (thus deleting the changelist) but it always returns again.

I have tried the below commands and while they work temporarily the changelist always reappears at a later date.

```
svn changelist --remove --recursive --cl "test" .

svn changelist --remove --changelist "test" --depth infinity .
```

svn st:

No reference to it there

```
?       .patch
?       path_to_file.java
?       path_to_file.java
M       path_to_file.java
M       path_to_file.properties

--- Changelist 'ignore-on-commit':
M       path_to_file\pom.xml
M       path_to_file\pom.xml
```

Edit to add imagine of tortoise:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Changelist does **not** exist after you commit it with `svn commit --changelist ...`, but still present in WC, if you commited *just files* in CL
2. `--remove` option doesn't destroy changelist, it just remove files from existing changelist (when properly called)

Check state of you current WC with `svn st` and show result here - I'm sure, you still have your changelist in it

Comment: Output of svn st added to original post

Comment: Tired commit but changelist keeps reappearing, if it's supposed to not exist after committing what is going on here? Is it a quirk of tortoise or subversion itself?

Comment: @user2028936 - 1) show `svn st` agan, whren you'll see this changelist - or screenshot of your commit form 2) you probably had enabled "Keep changelist" checkbox on [commit form](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/images/Changelist.png)

Comment: Screenshot of tortoise added to op. Keep Changelist not checked. If I then submit all files associated with the changelist under "Changelist Here" the changelist will disappear, no record will be found for it running svt st and it will not be found in any context menu in tortoise. After a time and randomly after modifying other files (even ones not originally associated with the changelist in the first place), the changelist will reappear.

Comment: @user2028936 - 1) if it's the latest TSVN (1.12) you can', I suppose, fill the bug report 2) If *some* changelists re-appear unpredictable after *correct* destruction I'll suspect *problems with this Working Copy* and I'll try to checkout fresh new (at least it will not inherit changelists from current WC) 3) you can (with existing WC) remove these "additions" from corresponding changelist by the usual way while every CL will not be empty.